# Let $(\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\},*)$ be a group of the rational numbers under multiplication and $(\mathbb Q,+)$ be the group of rational numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\},*)$ be a group of the rational numbers under multiplication and $(\mathbb Q,+)$ be the group of rational numbers under addition. Find the order of every element of this group.

Can somebody help me with this question? I don't know where to start.
I would really appreciate some help

Comment: Do you mean $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\},*)$ ?

Comment: Hint: in the first group an element $q$ of finite order must satisfy $q^n=1$ for some $n\geq 0$ and an element $q$ of finite order in the second group must satisfy $nq=1$ for some $n\geq 0$.

Comment: Should $nq=1$ or $nq=0$?

Comment: My bad @J.Dane the second one was $nq=0$.

Comment: Those are two different groups.  So those are two different quesitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ and $q\in \mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ solve $q^n=1$?

Which $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ and $q\in \mathbb Q$ solve $nq=0$?

Comment: For $q^n=1$ I find that every element different from $1$ and $-1$ have infinite order. Is that right?

Comment: As for $nq=0$, I don't know what to do. Can you help me ?

Comment: For $q^n$, you are correct. What is the order of $1$ $($the smallest $n>0$ such that $1^n = 1)$? What is the order of $-1$?

Comment: If $nq=0$ and $n>0$, what can you conclude about $q$?

Comment: The order of $1$ is $1$ and the order of $-1$ is $2$

Comment: For $nq=0$ $q$ must be $0$

Comment: Those are right!

Comment: All of those. You got the orders of $1$ and $-1$ right, and you got that $q$ must be $0$.